# Splitting a string with some characters with some ignored characters as well

Tags: c#, regex

There is a string: `"QARR_1 * QARR_1 * NPSH[*] + NPSH0"`. I want to split it into a string array (exactly of 4 items) to get output as: QARR_1, QARR_1, NPSH[*], NPSH0.

I understand, I should use Regex lookaround concepts here but, I am not able to achieve the desired result. Kindly help.

Comment: So you want to split on `<space>.<space> ` ? or is it not as simple as that?

Comment: @AkashM, I want to split the string on mathematical operator characters(+,-,\*,/) but not with "\[\*\]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do it like this without lookarounds:

`(\w+(?:\[\*\])?)`

[Test](https://regex101.com/r/zBORr2/2)

http://rextester.com/YHNRC51736

- a capured group `(`
- get or more word characters `\w+`
- with an optional non captured group `(?:\[\*\])?`

Comment: Kindly explain how the pattern is splitting the string into substrings?

Comment: It captures a group where this pattern `\w+(?:\[\*\])?` matches. For your provided data, this will match 4 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, the non-captured group format should start with  (?:..) ?

Comment: The non-captured group format is `(?:..)` and the `?` following it makes it optional. So an optional non captured group `(?:..)?`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
a = "QARR_1 * QARR_1 * NPSH[*] + NPSH0"
x= re.split(' \* | \+ ',a)
print x
```

['QARR_1', 'QARR_1', 'NPSH[*]', 'NPSH0']

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, well... this works in the regex tool I used:

```
\w+\[?\*?\]?
```

Not the most elegant, but pretty simple, so long as the input isn't broken like: "Abc12*]", "abc12[]", etc.

**How it works:**

- `\w+` this will greedily capture any sequence of word characters (keeps capturing until it runs out of characters that match), basically translates to: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`
- `\[?`, `\*?`, `\]?` well, to start, the backslash here is used as an escape character to get Regex to literally look for the characters `[`, `*` and `]`. They need to be escaped because they have a special meaning in Regex syntax otherwise. The `?` at the end of each part tells the Regex pattern to match for the character between 0 and 1 times. It is necessary to be able to capture it 0 times, to allow matches that don't have the characters (`[`, `*` ,`]` ) at the end to be made.

**A few examples of the kind of things it will match:**

- `apples123_121231_2133414[*]`
- `Ap1]`
- `Orange_11[*`
- `1ba222nnana*]`

**A few examples of the kinds of things it won't match:**
(note, cases where part of the word is highlighted, only the highlighted part will be matched.)

- `Pares]`*[
- ++++!!~+
- `111Grapes[`]
- `111Grapes[`]*

So, given the input you supplied, it should be fine... these are just a few things to be aware of.

Comment: Getting the desired result. Kindly explain your answer.

Comment: Sure! Gimme a minute.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to me now.